# Proving $(v,v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is a basis for $V.$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a real vector space and $T$ be a linear functional on $V.$ If $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is a basis for $\ker T$ and $v \in V - \ker(T)$ (so in particular, $v \neq 0)$, then $B = (v, v_1,\dots v_n)$ is a basis for $V$.

So I showed that $B$ is linearly independent since all $c_i = 0$ if $\sum_{i\leq n} c_i v_i = 0$ and $av = 0 \iff a = 0.$

I have to show $B$ spans $V$, if $w \in \ker T$, then it should be obvious. If $w \not\in \ker(T)$, I cannot show that it is exactly the multiple of $v$.

Comment: Knowing that $f$ is a linear functional on $V$, what is the dimension of $\ker T$ in regards to the dimension of $V$? Also, have you heard of the [rank-nullity theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)?

Comment: @Mariuslp, I mean it is just $\dim V - \dim Im(T) = \dim Ker(T)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $T$ is not identically zero, we have by rank-nullity that
$$\text{rank}(T) +\dim\ker(T) = \dim(V)$$
But since $T$ is a nonzero functional, $\text{rank}(T)=1$.
This leads to $\dim\ker T=\dim(V)-1$. Thus the size of $B=(v, v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is same as the dimension of $V$. As you have already checked linear independence, this shows that $B$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: I am not following, how is $T$ being a nonzero functional imply that $\dim Im(T)$ is $1$?

Comment: @Hawk Your comment belowe your question seems to imply you know **and** understand the dimensions theorem (or rank-nullity theorem), and what you ask follows at once from it.

Comment: Sorry this may seem to silly, but is $\dim \mathbb{F} = 1$?

Comment: @Hawk The dimension of $F$ as a vector space over itself is $1$ because any nonzero element of $F$ forms a basis of $F$.

Comment: @caffeinemachine, this may seem silly to write down, but simply because any number in $\mathbb{R}$ is a constant multiple of any number in....well...$\mathbb{R}$, hence it takes precisely $1$ vector span of all ...$\mathbb{R}$ and so every linear functional (except for the zero map) $T: V \to \mathbb{F}$ is really surjective.

Comment: @Hawk Yes that is right. This works for arbitrary fields.

Comment: For some reason it just did not seem that obvious to me when I was writing this..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the *rank-nullity theorem*. Note what you want to prove is true only if $T\ne 0$.